# build: Cannot determine build data storage root for project /home/abed/thingsboard

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

When I build my project, I see this error in IntelliJ IDEA:

> build: Cannot determine build data storage root for project
> /home/abed/thingsboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't access modify in your file in Linux
the solution push this command in your terminal where is your project

```
sudo chown -R $USER
```